# Read dataframe values by certain creteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading some data using panadas and this is dataframe:

|  | PARAMETER | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Param1 | 1.2 |
| 1 | Param2 | 5.0 |
| 2 | Param3 | 9.3 |
| 3 | Param4 | 30 |
| 4 | Param5 | 1500 |

What would be the best way to access values by parameter name? For example I need value of Param4 is there any way to say like read['Param'].value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be using `loc` like:

```
float(df.loc[df['PARAMETER']=='Param4']['VALUE']) # locate col PARAMETER and get VALUE
Out[81]: 30.0

# Or
df.loc[df['PARAMETER']=='Param4']['VALUE'].values
Out[94]: array([30.])
```

Another way would be to create a `dict` and access them like:

```
# Using a dictionary
d = dict(zip(df.PARAMETER,df.VALUE))
d['Param4']
Out[82]: 30.0

d['Param3']
Out[90]: 9.3
```

Comment: In the mean time I did on this way: Create two list for each columns and then join two list into dictionary:  



`col_one_list = fil2['PARAMETER'].tolist()`  

`col_two_list = fil2['VALUE'].tolist()`  

`res = {col_one_list[i]: col_two_list[i] for i in range(len(col_two_list))}`  

`print(res['Param4'])`

Answer (score 0):

1. I dont think there is a way to read with conditions.
2. But, you can do it using the following code.

   ```
    df[df['PARAMETER'] == 'Param4']['VALUE']
   ```